# In ListView.builder Bloc event triggered only once

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

[image][image]I m using Bloc for state management , I have my screen where I'm calling **event** in ListView.builder

```
   loadSuccess: (state) {
        return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: state.questions.size,
            itemBuilder: (
              context,
              index,
            ) {
              // ignore: avoid_unnecessary_containers

              debugPrint("this is index $index");
              debugPrint(
                  "this is user id ${state.questions.get(index).userId.getorCrash()}");

              context.read<UsersWatcherBloc>().add(
                    UsersWatcherEvent.watchAllUsers(
                      state.questions.get(index).userId.getorCrash(),
                    ),
                  );
              return Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                 ......)
```

But problem is that my event is triggered only one time and state changed one time but I want to change my event for each index :

Event.dart:

```
    part of 'users_watcher_bloc.dart';

   @freezed
    abstract class UsersWatcherEvent with _$UsersWatcherEvent {
    const factory UsersWatcherEvent.watchAllUsers(String uId) = _Started;
      }
```

Bloc.dart:

```
      @injectable
    class UsersWatcherBloc extends Bloc<UsersWatcherEvent, UsersWatcherState> {
   final IElearningRepository _iElearningRepository;

    UsersWatcherBloc(this._iElearningRepository)
  : super(const UsersWatcherState.initial());

    @override
   Stream<UsersWatcherState> mapEventToState(
   UsersWatcherEvent event,
 ) async* {
  yield* event.map(
  watchAllUsers: (e) async* {
    print("this is user id ${e.uId}");
    yield const UsersWatcherState.loadInProgress();
    yield* _iElearningRepository.watchAllUsers(e.uId.toString()).map(
          (failureOrUsers) => failureOrUsers.fold(
            (f) => UsersWatcherState.loadFailure(f),
            (users) {
              if (users.isEmpty) {
                return const UsersWatcherState.empty();
              }

              return UsersWatcherState.loadSuccess(users);
            },
          ),
        );
  },
);
 }
   }
```

Comment: what is `loadSuccess: (state) {`? what widget calls that `loadSuccess` callback?

Comment: @pskink : Blocbuilder<QuestionWatcherBloc, QuestionWatcherState>

Comment: [Blocbuilder](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/BlocBuilder-class.html) does not have it - it has no `loadSuccess` property

Comment: I have state load success

Comment: i have no idea what you mean - why dont you simply post that whole code which is part of `loadSuccess: (state) {` ?

Comment: ok let me edit the question

Comment: @pskink I added image please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 2 days struggle I found solution of this question, I have to wrap my container with another **BlocProvider** and use **dependency injection**

```
  loadSuccess: (state) {
        return ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: state.questions.size,
          itemBuilder: (
            context,
            index,
          ) {
            // ignore: avoid_unnecessar_containers

            return BlocProvider(
              create: (context) => getIt<UsersWatcherBloc>()
                ..add(
                  UsersWatcherEvent.watchCurrentUser(
                    state.questions.get(index).userId.getorCrash(),
                  ),
                ),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: leftPadding.w - 8.w,
                  right: rightpadding.w - 8.w,
                  bottom: bottomPadding.h,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
```